# C# XNA chatbox system

Tags: c#, xna, draw

I have been searching how I can make a chatbox in XNA, but I can't find a way how.
I want a chatbox in my game that displays like 10 messages a time. ( The messages can be store in like a List or something ) but I don't know how to do that. I know how to store it, but I don't really know how to put that inside a box ( probably in front of an image, but the width of the string can be bigger ). So what and how is the best way to do it? Thanks for reading the entire question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A chatbox consists out of very simple tools:

A list that holds all the messages

```
 List<string> messages = new List<string>();
```

A limiter on how many messages the chat can display

```
const int MAX_MESSAGES = 7;
```

and a playerInput class that handles all the input.

Feel free to go check out my basic chat system for xna: https://github.com/Mocrosoft/Xna-ChatSystem

If you have any questions feel free to pm me.